# Simplest iOS code creates strangest UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain error - reproducible

Tags: ios, ipad, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Check out this very basic iPad application:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    con = [[LaunchViewController alloc] init];
    [self.window setRootViewController:con];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

The `LaunchViewController` is nothing but a blank ViewController with the following method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    MFMailComposeViewController *emailDialog = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
}
```

When I run the program, I get the error: `_serviceViewControllerReady:error: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain error 1.)`

What is this? Any ideas? Note that my deployment target is 6.1 and the SDK is 7.0, if that makes any difference (because my iPad is not at 7.0, so I deploy for 6).

Comment: random question, are you doing anything related to UIAppearance?

Comment: Nope. Just did a search for that and found nothing in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the iPad and Xcode solved the problem. I'm dissapointed in Apple...